# Getting the Blank / White page, but only for one channel

Tags: channel, blank-screen

I have a channel called "Sub" that's essentially a catch-all for generic interior pages. All other channels (approximately 6) are loading fine, but the "sub" channel won't load anything in any template. It's not a template problem as I've tried it in multiple.

Here's the code I currently have in my template:

```
{embed="_includes/html_head"}
    Hello!
    {exp:channel:entries channel="sub"}
    <body id="interior" class="{categories limit='1'}{category_url_title}{/categories}">
        {embed="embeds/interior_supernav"}
        <div id="site-wrapper">
            <header id="main-header">
                <div id="site-header">
                    {embed="embeds/header_opening_tag" width="400" height="268"}
                        <h1>{exp:low_variables:parse var='full_organization_name'}</h1>
                        <nav id="main-navigation">
                            <h2><abbr title="College of Environmental Design">CED</abbr> Menu</h2>
                            <div class="groups">
                                {exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="1" exclude="1" css_id="none" css_class="site" status="open|featured"}
                                {exp:structure:nav start_from="/academics" show_depth="1" css_id="none" css_class="departments" include="19|143|21"}
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="interior-header">
                    {embed="embeds/interior_header_opening_tag"}
                        <h2>
                            {if section_title == ""}
                            {if {structure:page:entry_id} == {structure:top:entry_id}}
                            {exp:low_variables:parse var='full_organization_name'}
                            {if:else}
                            {structure:top:title}
                            {/if}
                            {if:else}
                            {section_title}
                            {/if}
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="interior-wrapper" {if sub_related_content == ""}class="no-related-content"{/if}>
                <nav id="interior-navigation">
                    {exp:structure:nav start_from="{segment_1}" show_depth="2" show_overview="yes" rename_overview="title"}
                </nav>
                <section id="interior-content">
                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h1>{title}</h1>
                            {if subhead}<h2>{subhead}</h2>{/if}
                        </header>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            {sub_content}
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section id="related-content">
                    {sub_related_content status="open|featured"}
                    {if "{channel_short_name}" == "events"}
                    {events_syndication_details}
                    <article class="minor-article {categories limit='1'}{category_url_title}{/categories}">
                        <a href="{page_url}" class="url">
                            {if entry_image}
                            <figure>
                                {exp:ce_img:pair src="{entry_image}" max="400"}
                                <img src="{made}">
                                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                            </figure>
                            {/if}
                            <header>
                                <h3><span class="tag-name">{categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/categories}</span></h3>
                                <h2>{title}</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p class="description">{entry_excerpt}</p>
                        </a>
                    </article>
                    {/events_syndication_details}
                    {/sub_related_content}
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        {embed="_includes/footer"}
        {embed="_includes/body_close"}
    </body>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    Goodbye!
{embed="_includes/html_foot"}
```

I get nothing between the "Hello!" and "Goodbye!". In fact if I remove everything but that and the entries tag pair I still get nothing:

```
{embed="_includes/html_head"}
    Hello!
    {exp:channel:entries channel="sub"}
    There?
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    Goodbye!
{embed="_includes/html_foot"}
```

"There?" doesn't show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fool. It was because I had the status set to "Featured" but wasn't looking for that. Updated to `{exp:channel:entries channel="sub" status="open|featured"}` and all is good in the world.

Sorry to waste anyone's time.

Comment: I love how my admitting how stupid I was got me some upvotes. Thanks! :)

Comment: +1 on your comment for meta value

Comment: I've been caught out like this on numerous occasions as well. Have you considered using `status="not closed"` instead? Saves you having to remember the individual statuses.

Comment: Great suggestion! Maybe others will actually learn from my mistake now!